# Xcode 11.2.1 - Swift 5 - Can't change main storyboard "Main" to another storyboard "Start"

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode11, rootviewcontroller

I have created a new storyboard named "Start.storyboard", but when I change Main Interface to "Start" nothing happened, The app just started with default storyboard "Main.storyboard".
I'm using Xcode 11.2.1 and iOS 13.2.3

[image: first image]
[image: second image]

Also I have tried to change the rootViewController from (AppDelegate) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as the code below:

```
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhoneVC")
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

but I got the same result, Main storyboard can't be changed.

Answer (score 60):

Go to `Info.plist` and update `Application Scene Manifest`. Change the storyboard name in default configuration of `Application Session Role`. Also make sure one of your ViewController in storyboard is marked as `is Initial View Controller`

[image]

Comment: amazing! work like a Sharm I don't know what I did, but it works. Not sure why we need that dropdown option in the target's general column)

Comment: Lifesaver. Thank you, huge help for those who are just learning the basics of iOS development.